# How can I use sockets with C-Panel?

Tags: javascript, cpanel

I want to make a multiplayer browser game. To do this I will need some way of quickly communicating the positions of all the players to all the clients on the server. I did some research and found that I could do this by using sockets. I then found that I could use node.js (https://nodejs.org/en/) and socket.io (https://socket.io/) to do this. However, I then found that C-Panel does not support node.js.

Is there any way I can implement the use of sockets in C-Panel with node.js or is there another way I can communicate the positions of players to all the clients?

Comment: If your hosting environment supports another programming language such as PHP then you could implement the server side of the socket functionality using that. The use of websockets is not exclusive to one programming language or framework

Comment: E.g. [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+websockets&oq=php+websockets&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.4966j0j4&client=ms-android-google&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8) might help you get started